Android studio cannot find modules even though the folder is open. what is the problem?
i have no idea why the red highlights are there and i can't run the file either
this is a flutter project. my flutter path is added. flutter doctor has only two issues, chrome executable(i use brave) and Visual studio(i am building apps for mobile). i have installed gradle in a separate folder. i think the issue is android studio not using gradle effectively. i have no idea what is happening. i am new to developing. thanks

can you please share the ss of the error you are facing in the android studio?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
